# How to convert PSCustomObject to array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have below JSON file that gets parsed with `ConvertFrom-Json` command:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "class": "class1",
    "price": "price1"
  },
  "item2": {
    "class": "class2",
    "price": "price2"
  }
}
```

This creates a `PSCustomObject` with two properties `item1` and `item2`. It produces below output:

```
item1                         item2
-----                         -----
@{class=class1; price=price1} @{class=class2; price=price2}
```

What I need instead is an array that prints:

```
name  class  price
----  -----  -----
item1 class1 price1
item2 class2 price2
```

Please note that I cannot modify the content of JSON file.

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution in my colleague's code:

```
$json = Get-Content -Path "<file-path>" | ConvertFrom-Json;
$json.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject] @{
    name = $_.Name;
    class = $_.Value.class;
    price = $_.Value.price;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one gives you all item-attributes and adds the name. The result is an array of objects:

```
$result = foreach($item in $json.PsObject.Properties) {
    Add-Member -in $item.value -NotePropertyName 'name' -NotePropertyValue $item.name –PassThru
}
```